# What is the unit used in ST_Distance()?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I wonder what the unit is of the float being returned from `ST_Distance`.

In the documentation it says:

> ...cartesian minimum distance (based on spatial ref) between two geometries in projected units.

What are these projected units?

The geometry is stored in a field: `geometry(Point,4326)`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think this is the most frequent question on PostGIS list over time :-)

If your data is in SRID 4326 and you use `geometry` type the result will not give any meaning. It is in degrees.

To get the result in meters just cast to `geography` type and `ST_Distance` will calculate the distance along the great circle instead and return in meters.

```
geometry(Point,4326)::geography
```

Another option is to project your data to some local projection based on a suitable unit. Then the answer will be in that unit.

Comment: Here is an example to find the distance between two rows in a table



SELECT ST_Distance(a.geom::geography, b.geom::geography) FROM pure_gis a, pure_gis b WHERE a.id='1' AND b.id='2';

Answer (score 7):

From http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html

> --Geometry example - units in planar degrees 4326 is WGS 84 long lat unit=degrees

If `ST_Distance` is given two geometries, it assumes those geometries are really in cartesian (or planar) coordinates. Thus, the units are the same as those in the coordinates -- usually metres or feet.

Your problem seems to be that your spatial reference system, 4326, actually uses (angular) geographic coordinates -- degrees long-lat -- so the results are in (somewhat meaningless) degrees.

Comment: Results are entirely meaningless, not even somewhat.

Comment: @PaulRamsey. Wouldn't they be the same as what i'd get "measuring" distances on a PlateCaree projection?

Comment: On a PC, you'd get linear units back and could at least say "OK, I know these units are subject to serious distortion". Getting "degrees" back, people might be tempted to think "aha, I have an angular distance here, just need to multiply by 2R and I'll have a linear distance". The units make a bad measurement potentially even more terribly misleading. And PC is so terrible I don't know why it gets a projection name... does't preserve distance, doesn't preserve direction, doesn't preserve area...

Comment: PC preserves distances along the equator and perpendicular to the equator. Aside from the required radians and radius conversions (admittedly, a very major inconvenience), the results of using ST_Distance on 4326 geometries will have the same general mixture of disadvantages and benefits that must be considered when using ST_Distance with projection geometries. Maybe the better debate should be (not "somewhat" versus "entirely" meaningless but) "Should ST_Distance and ST_Area even be allowed to return results given 4326 geometries?"