# Why is result of ST_Area or ST_Distance in SRID 4326 so small

Tags: postgis-2.0, measurements

there is one thing I do not understand when using the following Query in geometries which are all SRID 4326.

```
WITH s AS (SELECT * FROM de_sim_points_start WHERE id = 6545)
SELECT e.*, ST_Distance(e.geom, s.geom, true) as distance FROM de_sim_points_end AS e, s
WHERE ST_DWithin(e.geom, s.geom, 10000) 
AND e.parent_geometry = s.parent_geometry
ORDER BY distance
```

Result looks like

```
ID;parent_geometry;geom;distance
14033;"092730137137";"0101000020E6100000FE6FACF6AA8027409C2C8D9A0C744840";0.245261803286329
14031;"092730137137";"0101000020E6100000CCDBF35375812740825574F5F8734840";0.243900901309088
14029;"092730137137";"0101000020E6100000DCEE415F6A812740F7F2A95305744840";0.243893460499341
14026;"092730137137";"0101000020E61000003510CD8FB781274033F5CA0231744840";0.243011470475221
13535;"092730137137";"0101000020E610000039E0FBE271802740C6906BE8D6754840";0.242827846195593
14008;"092730137137";"0101000020E610000020C337BB18822740C5250EA2F3734840";0.242728103270343
13999;"092730137137";"0101000020E61000002A9807A3668227409825450CE4734840";0.242264477969627
13533;"092730137137";"0101000020E6100000C8AB5D1715812740968D666FCD754840";0.241653901891845
```

As far as I understand, distance results in SRID 4326 are in meters (I'm totally fine with that). So how can a point be just centimetres away from each other, when in reality they are serval meters away from each other? Image below uses point with id 14033 (orange)
[image: Plot]

EDIT: New Query with accepted answer looks like this and performs as expected

```
WITH s AS (SELECT * FROM de_sim_points_start WHERE id = 6545)
SELECT e.*, ST_Distance(e.geom::geography, s.geom::geography) as distance FROM de_sim_points_end AS e, s
WHERE ST_DWithin(e.geom::geography, s.geom::geography, 10000)
  AND e.parent_geometry = s.parent_geometry
  AND ST_Distance(e.geom::geography, s.geom::geography) > 2000
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76967/what-is-the-unit-used-in-st-distance Same Question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the measurements are always returned in **the units of chosen CRS**. WGS84 is defined in degrees of latitude or longitutde, thus it returns results in degrees.

If you want to obtain results in meters, you have two options:

1. Start using [geography](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html#PostGIS_Geography) type
2. Reproject your data into national coordinate system defined in meters

Comment: Number 1 is not an option. Number 2 might be possible, but comes at a cost. Also I need these Points later for routing (start and destination)

Comment: Isn't there a library or anything, that can convert between meters and degrees? BTW Backend is python based, so anything that can do the calcs in python is fine

Comment: I was wrong! Casting to geography works just fine. See updated Question.

Comment: By the way if you are just measuring distance between points, I strongly recommend using geometry operators instead of ST_Distance as they are much, much faster (with spatial indexes).

Comment: my goal is to find a random point which meets the condition more than 2000m and less than 10000m away from the start point. Also ST_DWithin already uses indexes and I do not know how to use ST_DWithin for the 2000m condition, thats why I use ST_Distance with an additional WHERE statement (updated Question)

Comment: It would be really interesting to see whether creating a donut buffer and doing ST_Within on it would be faster than the current implementation.
Or you can have a look at http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/geometry_distance_box.html - it might suit your needs just fine.

Comment: Tried the dount with buffers and it wasn't (back then). The above query runs at 30ms for the example point and the table holds ~17mio points so its fine